# Prevent "Recents" from loading secondary activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-recents

My App has two activities. Let's just call them "A" and "B" (B is a very heavyweight game). The way it's supposed to work is that "A" launches, validates the OBB package, mounts it and then launches "B" and passes some data to "B" and then "A" calls finish on itself since it's done.

It's important that "A" is the only thing that can launch/create "B".

What's happening is that when "B" gets terminated by the OS because of memory pressure, and then sometime later the user task switches back to it via the "recents", Android tries to create a new "B" activity.

In that situation, I want it to start a new "A" activity which will then create "B". Can someone tell me what I should look into to do this?

It's important that the user be able to switch between apps, take a phone call etc. and return to the already created/running "B" activity if it's still there and hasn't been terminated. If it HAS been terminated, tapping on it needs to launch activity "A" so that the OBB can be verified and remounted etc.

NOTE: I've had to simplify and gloss over some complex things to make the question short but let's assume that the preparation that "A" does cannot be moved to "B". I know that looks like a sane work around at this simplified level...but sadly it's not.

Comment: How are you passing data from A to B?

Comment: Via the intent's putExtra.

Answer (score 0):

Pass some data in an Intent when opening Activity B from A, then every time Activity B is created check if that data is there, otherwise create an Intent to Activity A and terminate Activity B.

Activity A:

```
Intent i = new Intent(activity, ActivityB.class);

// Pass your data or otherwise a boolean like so
i.putExtra("validIntent", true);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Activity B:

```
Bundle loginBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
boolean continueActivity = false;

if (loginBundle =! null) {
    if (loginBundle.getBoolean("validIntent");) {
        continueActivity = true; 
    }
}

if (!continueActivity) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityA.class));
    finish();
}
```

To preserve the data/boolean while paused, you could use saveInstanceState.

Comment: I did consider that but assumed that there was probably a more official way of doing things. Maybe there isn't?

Comment: How more official do you want?

Comment: Well for example, there are numerous intent flags. I tried reading through all of them and none seemed to fit exactly what I needed but I thought that I might have overlooked or misunderstood them.

Comment: You did not, apparently

Comment: Surprisingly, I tried this approach and it fails because when selecting the activity from the "recents", the OS passes back the original intent, already populated with values, so it seems like a legit start of the activity.

Comment: Damn, didn't know that. But then again, didn't you said you passed your data that way?

Comment: Yes some data is passed through the intents. I just didn't know the OS would essentially replay that intent.